# How can I get a "TOSHIBA EXT" USB Drive to mount?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

The trouble began when I was using Xfe File Manager to copy 2 GB of picture files to the "TOSHIBA EXT" USB disk on my Ubuntu 18.04. The copying processing
slowed to a crawl after copying 1.8 GB. After about an hour, the size of files copied had barely changed, I cancelled the process. I was going to shutdown the computer and noticed the light on the Toshiba disk was still blinking so I decided to wait. Shortly after, the power to my house went off.

When I started the computer, the Toshiba drive did not mount and was not listed in Xfe File Manager. I opened Files (Nautilus) and the Toshiba drive is listed in Files but is not mounted. I used properties to try to mount it but it will not mount. I used "Safely remove disk" to shut the Toshiba drive down and shutdown the computer. Waited 30 seconds and rebooted the computer.

This did not change anything.

I know the computer is communicating with the "TOSHIBA EXT" drive because the the light on the drive blinks and goes on and off all the time the computer is running. Plus it is listed in Files, Disks and other places.

Following are links to websites I have looked for help and followed many of their suggestions. All of which did not mount the "TOSHIBA EXT" drive.

Even though [this is for ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547965/mounting-external-hard-disk-for-all-users-at-start-up-in-ubuntu-14-04), I figured maybe the "Disks" program would be updated on Ubuntu 18.04 and might work ...

I tried using "Disks" to setup the code to mount it in the `/etc/fstab` file. That code did not work to mount it. It did add this code to the file:

```
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="TOSHIBA EXT" UUID="BA42DA8242DA4335" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="88fa34b8-01"
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_MQ04UBD200_39JET9F6T-part1 /mnt/ata-TOSHIBA_MQ04UBD200_39JET9F6T-part1 ntfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The `/etc/fstab` file also has this code for a Seagate USB drive which does mount:

```
UUID=382bc1ca-a70a-4212-bb91-362c48d82a8e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I used [this code](https://linuxhint.com/uuid_storage_devices_linux/) to get UUID of a disk drive:

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo blkid | grep UUID=
[sudo] password for rob: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="382bc1ca-a70a-4212-bb91-362c48d82a8e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="07f967cf-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Seagate GoFlex" UUID="BEB8C0D6B8C08DF9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="11ca0efb-01"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="TOSHIBA EXT" UUID="BA42DA8242DA4335" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="88fa34b8-01"
```

I ran: `man mount` - and took a shot at this:

```
sudo mount --source /media/rob UUID=BA42DA8242DA4335 --target /media/rob
```

The above did not work.

Following [this article on file permissions](https://itsfoss.com/set-write-permission-ext4-partition-ubuntu-linux/):

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ ll /media/$USER
total 48
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 root root  4096 Oct 15 18:56  ./
drwxrwxr-x  5 root root  4096 Oct 15 14:39  ../
drwxrwxrwx  1 rob  rob  40960 Mar 24  2021 'Seagate GoFlex'/
```

The above shows the owner as "root" on what would be "TOSHIBA EXT" while I am listed as the owner on the "Seagate GoFlex”. I cannot change the ownership because the disk is not mounted.

Next, I ran [this code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125158/cannot-mount-usb-hard-drive):

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 "/media/rob/Toshiba Ext"
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

I ran: `fuser -m "/media/rob/TOSHIBA EXT" -m /media/rob`.

This returns a bunch of numbers. None of which look familiar.

I changed `/etc/fstab` file to have this mounting code:

```
UUID=382bc1ca-a70a-4212-bb91-362c48d82a8e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_MQ04UBD200_39JET9F6T-part1 /mnt/ata-TOSHIBA_MQ04UBD200_39JET9F6T-part1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The Toshiba disk has always been plugged into a USB3 port.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on an AMD® A4-5300 apu with radeon(tm) hd graphics

Can anyone tell me how to get the "TOSHIBA EXT" USB drive to mount?

Comment: Definitely do a error correction in Windows.

Comment: Can you run "21.10 install media" to repair the disk in Ubuntu 18.04 without installing Ubuntu 21.10 @ubfan1? If so, how?

Comment: Boot the install media, and select the "Try" option.  Then you can run a terminal and whatever checks the ntfs filesystem (something new for 21.10, don't know what myself). Maybe not even in 20.10, might need a later kernel kernel.  The Windows option might be easier, and is certainly more tested for ntfs repair.

Comment: If possible, use Windows to repair a Windows file system (NTFS, FAT32, exFAT), and use Linux to repair a Linux file system (for example ext4). Only if Windows is not available, you should try to repair NTFS with Ubuntu. (The Linux tools to repair FAT32 are more developed and tested than those for NTFS, but still not or par with the tools in Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

**ntfsfix** solved the problem of mounting my **TOSHIBA EXT** drive.
If your attempts to mount a drive produces this error:
**Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).**
Before running the  below code, read on to learn how to get the correct
**/dev/sdb1** code and **UUID=** for your drive.
Here is the mount command I ran which produced the above error:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 UUID=BA42DA8242DA4335
```

If you get this error, the **ntfsfix** program may solve your problem too.
[This link tells you what ntfsfix does](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ntfsfix.8.html)
I got this information from Richard Rublev's answer on this [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140870/how-to-mount-external-hdd-on-18-04-cant-find-in-etc-fstab).
I pretty much got the same results as he shows in his answer. See my results below.

I downloaded **ntfs-3g_2017.3.23.orig.tar.gz** [from launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.3).
I extracted it and ran the **configure** file.
The configure file is in the folder you extracted the tar.gz file into.
In the terminal [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[t] type the path to the **configure** file plus `configure` 
An easy way to get the entire path and file name is to right click
on the **configure** file in Files (Nautilus) file listing and select **Copy**.
In the terminal right click at the command prompt and select **Paste**.
Then press [Enter].
When **configure** is done processing, it will tell you
you can run 'make'.
Type `make` at the command prompt and press [Enter].
When 'make' is done, the program is ready to use.

Before you run the **ntfsfix** program you need the drive code.
At the command prompt, type `sudo blkid | grep UUID=`
This will give you a listing of the drives your computer recognizes
even if they are not mounted. In my case the listing is:

> rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo blkid | grep UUID=
> [sudo] password for rob: 
> /dev/sda1: UUID="382bc1ca-a70a-4212-bb91-362c48d82a8e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="07f967cf-01"
> /dev/sdc1: LABEL="Seagate GoFlex" UUID="BEB8C0D6B8C08DF9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="11ca0efb-01"
> /dev/sdb1: LABEL="TOSHIBA EXT" UUID="BA42DA8242DA4335" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="88fa34b8-01"
> rob@rob-MS-7721:~$

I needed **/dev/sdb1** for my **TOHSIBA EXT** drive which would not mount.
Notice in the listing above the three drives all have a different
/dev/sd## code.

At the command prompt type this command: `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` in my case.
Replace **/dev/sdb1** with your drive code shown in the listing you got from the **blkid**
command you ran (shown above).
You should see something like this when you run your code for the drive that
won't mount with the `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` command.

> rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
> Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
> FAILED
> Attempting to correct errors... 
> Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
> Reading $MFT... OK
> Reading $MFTMirr... OK
> Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
> Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
> Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
> Setting required flags on partition... OK
> Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
> Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
> NTFS volume version is 3.1.
> NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
> rob@rob-MS-7721:~$

If this was your problem, the drive should mount now.
If your drive is listed in Files (Nautilus), you can mount it from there.
It should also mount by doing a [Restart].
The manual should have a listing for ntfsfix even before you install it.
In the terminal type:

```
man ntfsfix
```

and press [Enter].

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)